# Message Attachments missing when posting message to Slack App Home channel

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I've built a [Workspace App](https://api.slack.com/workspace-apps-preview) for Slack, which now comes with a channel (under the Apps header), where a user can send messages to the app itself. This triggers a 
*message.app_home* event, that my backend receives. I want to respond to that message, using [chat.postMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage), but only the message text appears in the response. None of the attachments I send along appear in the channel. Returning this structure as part of a JSON response to a Slash Command request works correctly.

Here are the attachments structure I sending along:

```
(
    {
        "title": "Create a space, optionally setting its name and adding other users",
        "text": "`/luffa create [space name] [teammates]`\nExample: `/luffa create Marketing Campaign 2018 @john @kate`",
        "color": SLACK_COLOR,
    },
    {
        "title": "Start a new meeting, optionally strating it in the space matching the provided name",
        "text": "`/luffa start [space name]`\nExample: `/luffa start Marketing Campaign 2018`",
        "color": SLACK_COLOR,
    },
    {
        "title": "Search Luffa",
        "text": "`/luffa search [query]`\nExample: `/luffa search interviews before:Yesterday `",
        "color": SLACK_COLOR,
    },
    {
        "text": "There is more help available in our Help Center: https://help.okluffa.com/",
    },
)
```

I am using the [slackclient](https://pypi.org/project/slackclient/) Python library to wrap my calls to the Slack API.

There is no error message returned and the structure seems to be correct based on the [documentation](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments). Is there something missing there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out that the data structure I was passing to [slackclient](https://pypi.org/project/slackclient/) 1.2.1 was a `tuple` of objects. The library will only serialize as JSON `list` or `dict` objects. (See `slackrequest.py`, line 94, `if isinstance(v, (list, dict)):`). Passing a tuple, or any other iterable for that matter, will not be serialized correctly and the Slack API will disregard the attachments. That was not an issue with a JSON response to a request, since Python's JSON serializer converts all iterables to a JSON array.

I solved the issue by passing in a `list` to the [slackclient](https://pypi.org/project/slackclient/) method.

Answer (score 1):

Something small to check - try removing the extra commas on each last value in your `attachments` structure, as those are causing validation errors when plugged [into the Slack message tester here](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder?msg=%7B%22text%22%3A%22I%20am%20a%20test%20message%20http%3A%2F%2Fslack.com%22%2C%22attachments%22%3A%5B%7B%22title%22%3A%22Create%20a%20space%2C%20optionally%20setting%20its%20name%20and%20adding%20other%20users%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22%60%2Fluffa%20create%20%5Bspace%20name%5D%20%5Bteammates%5D%60%5CnExample%3A%20%60%2Fluffa%20create%20Marketing%20Campaign%202018%20%40john%20%40kate%60%22%2C%22color%22%3A%22red%22%7D%2C%7B%22title%22%3A%22Start%20a%20new%20meeting%2C%20optionally%20strating%20it%20in%20the%20space%20matching%20the%20provided%20name%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22%60%2Fluffa%20start%20%5Bspace%20name%5D%60%5CnExample%3A%20%60%2Fluffa%20start%20Marketing%20Campaign%202018%60%22%2C%22color%22%3A%22danger%22%7D%2C%7B%22title%22%3A%22Search%20Luffa%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22%60%2Fluffa%20search%20%5Bquery%5D%60%5CnExample%3A%20%60%2Fluffa%20search%20interviews%20before%3AYesterday%20%60%22%2C%22color%22%3A%22red%22%7D%2C%7B%22text%22%3A%22There%20is%20more%20help%20available%20in%20our%20Help%20Center%3A%20https%3A%2F%2Fhelp.okluffa.com%2F%22%7D%5D%7D):

[image: Slack validation error]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. However, it turns out the issue was with the Python library I was using to wrap my calls to the API.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Thanks for posting your answer :)